# Setting DataContext to multiple sources while respecting MVMM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I have read the other questions regarding a matter similar to this, but it dosn't quite ask for a solution to this simple scenario:

```
namespace View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PuzzleSelectionScreen.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PuzzleSelectionScreen : Page
    {
        public PuzzleSelectionScreen(PuzzleControllerVM puzzleControllerVM, ScreenSwitcher screenSwitcher)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // My button needs a command in screenSwitcher (View) to change Page ..
            // .. with a Property (puzzle data) from puzzleControllerVM (View Model)
            this.DataContext = puzzleControllerVM;
            this.DataContext = screenSwitcher;
        }
    }
}
```

I can stick `screenSwitcher` in puzzleControllerVM and access all the properties just by `this.DataContext = puzzleControllerVM;`, but this would violate MVMM as `screenSwitcher` contains many View objects.

What I do above, the `DataContext` will assign to `screenSwitcher` only because it is executed last, but I want a convenient solution so my DataContext will have access to both sources without having to stick my `screenSwitcher` in my view model class `PuzzleControllerVM`.

Comment: Create two constructors.  One that has a parameter PuzzleControllerVM and one that has the parameter ScreenSwitcher,

Comment: It sounds like PuzzleSelectionScreen View / VM should be a child of ScreenSwitcher View / VM

Comment: Why does `ScreenSwitcher` "contain many View objects"? *This* violates the MVVM pattern. Switching screens should be part of the view model and not include any view objects.

Answer (score 0):

U can create a new type which hold reference to both and set the datacontext to the instance of the type.

Something like this

```
    public PuzzleSelectionScreen(PuzzleControllerVM puzzleControllerVM, ScreenSwitcher screenSwitcher)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Hybrid { PuzzleControllerVM = puzzleControllerVM, ScreenSwitcher = screenSwitcher };
    }

    public class Hybrid
    {
       public PuzzleControllerVM PuzzleControllerVM { get; set; }
       public ScreenSwitcher ScreenSwitcher { get; set; }
    }
```